# SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499 Chain validation failed

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I added SHA256 and SHA1 keys to Firebase console. Enabled Device Check API in console. After doing all of these, I downloaded new google-services.json file and implemented it in my project. Still it gives errors on emulator.

```
[  +52 ms] D/EGL_emulation(13977): app_time_stats: avg=1078.88ms min=4.84ms max=37911.18ms count=36
[ +841 ms] E/zzf     (13977): Problem retrieving SafetyNet Token: 7: 
[  +64 ms] W/System  (13977): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
[ +105 ms] E/FirebaseAuth(13977): [GetAuthDomainTask] IOException occurred: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed
[  +43 ms] E/zzf     (13977): Failed to get reCAPTCHA token with error [An internal error has occurred.]- calling backend without app verification
[  +15 ms] W/System  (13977): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
[   +8 ms] D/EGL_emulation(13977): app_time_stats: avg=38990.40ms min=38990.40ms max=38990.40ms count=1
[  +16 ms] D/EGL_emulation(13977): app_time_stats: avg=54.82ms min=4.19ms max=752.07ms count=18
[  +68 ms] E/FirebaseAuth(13977): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499 Chain validation failed
[   +4 ms] E/flutter (13977): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
[        ] E/flutter (13977): #0      MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber.<anonymous closure> (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:599:35)
[        ] E/flutter (13977): #1      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1434:47)
[        ] E/flutter (13977): #2      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
[        ] E/flutter (13977): #3      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
[        ] E/flutter (13977): #4      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
[        ] E/flutter (13977): #5      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:14)
[        ] E/flutter (13977): #6      _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:706:11)
[        ] E/flutter (13977): #7      _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:663:7)
[        ] E/flutter (13977): #8      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1418:47)
[        ] E/flutter (13977): #9      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
[        ] E/flutter (13977): #10     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1236:7)
[        ] E/flutter (13977): #11     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1276:23)
[        ] E/flutter (13977): #12     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1426:13)
[        ] E/flutter (13977): #13     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
[        ] E/flutter (13977): #14     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1236:7)
[        ] E/flutter (13977): #15     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1276:23)
[        ] E/flutter (13977): #16     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
[        ] E/flutter (13977): #17     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
[        ] E/flutter (13977):
```

Basic Code:

```
 Future<void> phoneVerify() async {
    print(telefonController.text);
    try {
      await firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: telefonController.text,
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {},
        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {},
        codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {},
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
      );
    } catch (c) {
      telefonController.clear();
      print(c.toString());
      Navigator.pop(context);
      if (c == 'invalid-verification-code') {
      } else {}
    }
  }
```

Is there a step I skipped?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ,Enabled Device Check API in console is work for me !